# How to make program to overwrite itself during execution in go

Tags: go, overwrite, self

I tried to write a program that open itself, reads itself and looks for a certain address or bytes to substitute with an other value.

My objective is to make a program that understands if it's the first time that it's running or not by modifying some bytes the first time it runs (and I don't really like to create a file outside of my program)

The executable can read itself but when it tryes to self-overwrite it throws an error (file used by an other process... As expected)

Is there a way for the program to overwrite itself? If not maybe I can modify just a part of the program that contains just data?
Is there an other simple solution I am not aware of?

(I'm using both Linux and windows as OS.)

Comment: "Is there another simple solution I am not aware of?" The simple solution is to write a sentinel file somewhere in $HOME (use $XDG_CONFIG_HOME if set), which you "don't really like". Also, it is questionable if the executing user even has permission to overwrite the binary. That being said, how are you trying to overwrite the program? os.Rename should work on Linux at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround can be (because it doesn't overwrite itself, it just creates an other file):

1. copy all content of the original executable
2. modify what I need
3. rename di original executable to a fixed name "old version"
4. write the modified bytes to "original name" (the modified executable)
5. launch the new executable just created
6. either have the original executable self delete or delete it from the modified executable just created

I think this gets the job done even if not on the cleanest way (the program has to start from beginning but i guess this is unavoidable)...

If someone still know a better way you are more the welcome to write your idea.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your objective is to find out if the program has been run previously or not. Instead of going with the idea you presented why not create a file, could be any file, check upon running if the file is there or not. If it's there then it has been run before else not.

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to avoid because I don't want the end user to find the file in any way and delete it.

Comment: The user can also delete the compiled program if he wants. What's the difference between modifying the binary itself and modifying an external file?
Also if finding the file is the issue, you can make it harder for the user to discover it. Both on Linux and windows you can create it as a hidden file. Also, on windows, you can modify a registry entry which definitely make it hard for a user to discover it.